# styling bracketed content that follows the A link in an LI element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have built a sitemap in a WordPress site that shows links for pages, posts, archives, categories and authors and I am trying to work out how to target the bracketed content (eg (6) ) with css so I can make it a lighter colour than the link and bullet.

I want:

- the bullet to be the std non link colour (in this case #000). I know how
  to do this
- the link to be the std link colour (in this case #F00). I know how to do this
- and the minor / bracketed content following the link to be a lighter colour (in this case #999). I am stuck with this

The output html looks like so:

```
Post
<li><a href="/test/">Test</a> <span>May 20, 2017</span></li>

Archive
<li><a href='/2017/05/'>May 2017</a>&nbsp;(6)</li>

Category
<li><a href="/category/uncategorised/" >Uncategorised</a> (8)</li>
```

For the Posts there is a span around the date so I am able to target that span with:

```
#sitemap li a + span
```

However how do I target the bracketed content in the Archive and Category links that do not have a span so I can make them #999 in colour?

Ideally I could add a span around the Archive and Category numbers with a filter but I don't know the code to do this and if a css solution is available I would prefer that for simplicity sake.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't.  You can either target the whole `li` and then override with `li a`, but that will style the bullet also - or you can wrap the desired text in a `span` like your example, and address it separately.

Comment: You could style the colour for the `<li>` itself, because they all contain only `<a>` and `<span>` elements apart from the number and you already style the colour of those. However if your `<li>`s will contain more text then the only way is to use a span. But as you already use a span I don't see the problem in using them in all `<li>`s - it would keep it consistent and easier to style in the long run e.g. just change the colour of one span element instead of multiple elements and complicated CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Agreed re the span. That would be my preferred method. But to do that in WordPress I need filters to add into functions.php - does anyone know the filters to use for archives, categories and authors to wrap a span around the bracketed content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can solve this using the `before` pseudo element to style the bullet however you please.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  color: #999;
}

ul li::before {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  margin: -1px 10px 0 -15px;
  width: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul li a {
  color: #f00;
}

ul li span {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/test/">Test</a> <span>May 20, 2017</span></li>
  <li><a href='/2017/05/'>May 2017</a>&nbsp;(6)</li>
  <li><a href="/category/uncategorised/" >Uncategorised</a> (8)</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Thanks itodd. Nifty solution. That definitely works. To see the faux bullet on my site I had to add "list-style: none;" to the li (my css base must be different). It seems kind of hacky to hide the bullet and then replace with faux bullet but perhaps this is the only way to do it (as css solution, without wordpress filters). Thanks for your help.